# how to remove null from object property array

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am using ngFor within component. I have the following object.

```
{"name":"name_text","values":[null,{"id":1,"text":"text1"},{"id":2,"text":"text2"},{"id":3,"text":"text3"},null,{"id":5,"text":"text5"},{"id":6,"text":"text6"},{"id":7,"text":"text7"}]}
```

this is my ngFor in component:

```
<option *ngFor="let val of enumeration.values" value="{{val}}">{{val["text"]}}</option>
```

Problem is that there are null objects in array so i am unable to run it. Can somebody help me and give me some hints how can i remove them?

Thanks

Comment: Try to do first filter the array and then use the ngFor

    <option *ngFor="let val of enumeration.values.filter(val => val !== null)" value="{{val}}">{{val["text"]}}</option>

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#filter` to get rid of the `null` entries and modify the original object.

```js
var obj = {"name":"name_text","values":[null,{"id":1,"text":"text1"},{"id":2,"text":"text2"},{"id":3,"text":"text3"},null,{"id":5,"text":"text5"},{"id":6,"text":"text6"},{"id":7,"text":"text7"}]},
    res = obj.values.filter(v => v);
    obj.values = res;

    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Nice use of .values()

Comment: this.enumeration = data.get(enumName);
this.enumeration.values = this.enumeration.values.filter(v => v); says there is no such a property "filter"

Comment: @MartinFric There's no such property 'filter' **or** 'filter' is not a function?

Comment: property "filter" does not exist on type "Object". cause enumeration is object which has property as array of objects. maybe i need to remove array from object filter it and then rewrite to object?

Comment: @MartinFric Try to assign the filtered array to a newly made `res` variable and then assign it to the `values` array (look at my edit).

Comment: @Kind user. I cannot assign type Object to array. I must check that type

Comment: @MartinFric I've made a plunker for you. https://plnkr.co/edit/TZbkXWc9xhAKQpxEk9zm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery grep function. Hope it helps you.

YourArray = jQuery.grep(YourArray, function(n, i){

return (n != "" && n!= null);

});

Comment: dont want to add jquery to my node modules.

Comment: If that is the case, please try filtering your array in server side itself so that, you will not have to bother about null values in client side.